# React property is undefined when trying to use array map function

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, dictionary

I am receiving a single object from my API, which contains some simple properties and an array of strings. I am trying to display this array using the map function, though when I try to use the map function, my app breaks throwing "TypeError: tags is undefined". The code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import VideoPlayer from "../Video/VideoPlayer";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class VideoDetails extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = 
    {
        video: {}
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://localhost:44362/api/Video/" + this.props.id;
    fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({ video: json }))
  }

render() {
    const {video} = this.state;
    const tags = video.tags;

    console.log(tags);
    console.log(video);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{video.title}</h1>
            <VideoPlayer />

            <h2>Video ID {video.id}</h2>
            <br></br>
            <h3>Description</h3>

            <p>{video.description}</p>

            <h3>Tags</h3>
            <ul>
                {
                    tags.map(
                        (tag) => 
                        (
                            <li>{tag}</li>
                        )
                    )
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default VideoDetails;
```

I have a feeling it doesn't know that video.tags is an array, but I'm not too sure how to resolve this. I can remove the map function and directly print out the array directly just fine, but map doesn't work. I can't quite find out what it is I'm doing wrong here, a lot of examples I come across seem to be dealing directly with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because as soon as the component renders for the first time you are trying to run a loop on the tags property (which is undefined at initial page load). Try the below condition to prevent the issue

```
{tags && tags.map((tag) => <li>{tag}</li>) }
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, I knew it would be something small and silly I overlooked!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because initially your state object - video is empty. componentDidMount will be executed after the first render on the client-side. So, basically, the render method will be called first and then componentDidMount. Thus, since initially, you don't have tags key in the video state object - your const tags variable is undefined.

You should add a check in the render method - to check if the tags array is present during rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Issue:
The problem here is that your component is trying to render "tags" before it is fetched or before it is set to an array.

Solution:

1. Give tags a default value of 0.

   `this.state =  { video: { tags:0} }`

2)Make changes to the map section

```
{
this.state.video.tags===0?'Loading':this.state.video.tags.map( (tag) => 
(
<li>{tag}</li>
)
)
}
```